How do I add the IP of my nodes as an attribute into my Prometheus metrics
I have node-exporter-prometheus-node-exporter and kube-state-metrics running in my Kubernetes cluster. I am getting the metrics using a VictoriaAgent running as a deployment in my cluster. For the VictoriaAgent deployment I am using a Kubernetes configmap and deployment resource.
These are the content of the resources.
Configmap
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vmagent-config
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  vmagent.yaml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: "hke"
        scrape_interval: 30s
        metrics_path: /metrics
        relabel_configs:
        - target_label: k8s_node_ip
          source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_address_InternalIP]
        - target_label: client_cluster
          replacement: "achebe-cluster"
        - target_label: client_email
          replacement: "admin@example.com"
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          target_label: instance
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - "kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080"
          - targets:
            - "node-exporter-prometheus-node-exporter.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:9100"
      - job_name: "hke-cadvisor"
        scheme: https
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
          insecure_skip_verify: true
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: node
        relabel_configs:
          - target_label: __address__
            replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
            regex: (.+)
            target_label: __metrics_path__
            replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor

Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vmagent
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vmagent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vmagent
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: vmagent
          image: victoriametrics/vmagent:v1.94.0
          args:
            - -promscrape.config=/etc/vmagent-config/vmagent.yaml
            - -remoteWrite.url=https://metrics.hostspacecloud.com/api/v1/write
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/vmagent-config
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8429
              name: web
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: vmagent-config
       

Right now this is what my VictoriaMetric table looks like when I run this query kube_node_status_condition

I have tried something similar but this time with Otel opentelemetry-collector using helm and I was able to get the instance IP using the same query kube_node_status_condition .
This is the code I used for opentelemetry-collector;
opentelemetry-collector:
  enabled: true
  mode: daemonset

  image:
    repository: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
  extraEnvs:
    - name: K8S_NODE_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
    - name: K8S_NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
  presets:
    hostMetrics:
      enabled: true
    clusterMetrics:
      enabled: false
    kubernetesAttributes:
      enabled: true
    kubernetesEvents:
      enabled: true
  config:
    receivers:
      prometheus:
        config:
          scrape_configs:
            - job_name: "hke"
              scrape_interval: 30s
              metrics_path: /metrics
              relabel_configs:
              - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
                target_label: instance
              static_configs:
                - targets:
                    - "kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080"
                - targets:
                    - "node-exporter-prometheus-node-exporter.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:9100"
            - job_name: "hke-cadvisor"
              scheme: https
              tls_config:
                ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
                insecure_skip_verify: true
              bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
              kubernetes_sd_configs:
                - role: node
              relabel_configs:
                - target_label: __address__
                  replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
                - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
                  regex: (.+)
                  target_label: __metrics_path__
                  replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor   
    processors:
      batch:
        send_batch_size: 5000
        timeout: 500ms
      resourcedetection:
        detectors:
          - k8snode
        k8snode:
          node_from_env_var: K8S_NODE_NAME
      attributes:
        actions:
          - action: insert
            key: client.cluster
            value: ""
          - action: insert
            key: client.email
            value: ""
          - action: insert
            key: k8s.node.name
            value: "${K8S_NODE_NAME}"
          - action: insert
            key: k8s.node.ip
            value: "${K8S_NODE_IP}"
      k8sattributes:
        extract:
          metadata:
            - k8s.node.name
            - k8s.namespace.name
            - k8s.pod.name
        passthrough: false
      memory_limiter:
        check_interval: 1s
        limit_percentage: 70
        spike_limit_percentage: 30

    extensions:
      health_check: {}
      k8s_observer:
        auth_type: serviceAccount
        observe_pods: true
        observe_nodes: true

    exporters:
      debug:
        verbosity: detailed
      prometheusremotewrite/prom:
        endpoint: "https://xxx.xxx.com/api/v1/write"
        headers:
          X-Scope-OrgID: common
        timeout: 20s

      prometheusremotewrite/cortex:
        endpoint: "https://xx.xx.com/api/v1/push"
        headers:
          X-Scope-OrgID: common
        timeout: 20s
        
    service:
      extensions:
        - health_check
      pipelines:
        metrics:
          receivers:
            - prometheus
          processors:
            - resourcedetection
            - k8sattributes
            - attributes
            - batch
          exporters:
            - prometheusremotewrite/prom
            - prometheusremotewrite/cortex
        

This is what is expected;

As you can see the difference between the two images, one was able to add the instance IP as attribute using Otel Opentelemetry Collector but I couldnt with Victoria Metric Agent.
How can I relabel or add the instance IP as an attribute in the metric.

the same result could be achieved with the following vmagent configuration:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vmagent
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vmagent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vmagent
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: vmagent
          image: victoriametrics/vmagent:v1.94.0
          args:
            - -promscrape.config=/etc/vmagent-config/vmagent.yaml
            - -remoteWrite.url=https://metrics.hostspacecloud.com/api/v1/write
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/vmagent-config
          env:
          # expose node ip to the container env variables
          # it could be referenced via %{ENV_VAR} syntax at configuration file
          # see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#environment-variables for details
          - name: K8S_NODE_IP
            valueFrom:
             fieldRef:
               fieldPath: status.hostIP 
          - name: K8S_NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
             fieldRef:
               fieldPath: spec.nodeName 
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8429
              name: web
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: vmagent-config

At first, you should expose env variable K8S_NODE_IP with kubernetes downward api.
Next, you should use it at relabeling configuration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vmagent-config
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  vmagent.yaml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: "hke"
        scrape_interval: 30s
        metrics_path: /metrics
        relabel_configs:
        - target_label: k8s_node_name
          replacement: %{K8S_NODE_NAME}
        - target_label: k8s_node_ip
          replacement: %{K8S_NODE_IP}
        - target_label: client_cluster
          replacement: "achebe-cluster"
        - target_label: client_email
          replacement: "admin@example.com"
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - "kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080"
          - targets:
            - "node-exporter-prometheus-node-exporter.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:9100"
      - job_name: "hke-cadvisor"
        scheme: https
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
          insecure_skip_verify: true
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: node
        relabel_configs:
          - target_label: __address__
            replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
          - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
            regex: (.+)
            target_label: __metrics_path__
            replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor

Please note, given configuration will always use IP and NodeName of instance where vmagent or opentelemetry collector pod was scheduled.
There is also a guide for kubernetes monitoring with VictoriaMetrics components https://docs.victoriametrics.com/guides/k8s-monitoring-via-vm-single/
